# VBA Excel Alphabetized listbox

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, listbox

In VBA for Excel, I have already written a code to give a ListBox a rowsource, but how do I make that list be in alphabetical order without a previously written function to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `lvMyList.Sorted = True`?

Comment: I did not try that, but I did figure it out, Thanks!

Comment: @Jon would be interesting to have the proposed solution shared on the site, properly setting the question as answered. This way you can help other developers with the same quesion.